# firebase firestore data is not able to get and print in recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, syntax-error

> kotlin code for android app
>
> This is the code for reading the data from the firebase firestore database.. but unable to get data from firestore database where is the falt in the code

these two Error show in logcat:

***2021-05-09 02:12:26.315 19481-19481/? E/raunak.alison_: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000***

***2021-05-09 02:12:26.828 19481-19481/com.raunak.alison_4 E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.df.effect.conflict"***

```
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import com.google.firebase.firestore.auth.User
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_home.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.comment_list_view.*
import java.util.*

class home : AppCompatActivity() {
    var selectCategery = Funny
    lateinit var commentAdopter: CommentAdopter
    val comment_detail = arrayListOf<data_constructer>()
    val commentClollectionRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(Reference_data)


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)


        commentAdopter = CommentAdopter(comment_detail)
        recycler_list_view.adapter = commentAdopter
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recycler_list_view.layoutManager = layoutManager
        commentClollectionRef.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->
                for (document in snapshot.documents) {
                    val data = document.data


                    val name = data!![USERNAME] as String
                    val timestamp = data[TIMESTAMP] as Date
                    val comment = data[COMMENT] as String
                    val numLikes = data[NUM_LIKES] as Long
                    val numComments = data[NUM_COMMENTS] as Long
                    val documentId = document.id

                    val newThoughts = data_constructer(
                        name,
                        timestamp,
                        comment,
                        numLikes.toInt(),
                        numComments.toInt(),
                        documentId
                    )

                    comment_detail.add(newThoughts)


                }
                commentAdopter.notifyDataSetChanged()

            }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->

                Log.e("Exception", "Could not add post:$exception")

            }

    }


    fun mainFunnyClicked(view: View) {


        if (selectCategery == Funny) {
            main_funnyBtn.isChecked = true
            return
        }
        main_seriousBtn.isChecked = false
        main_crazyBtn.isChecked = false
        main_populerBtn.isChecked = false
        selectCategery = Funny

    }

    fun mainSeriousClicked(view: View?) {
        if (selectCategery == SERIOUS) {
            main_seriousBtn.isChecked = true
            return
        }
        main_funnyBtn.isChecked = false
        main_crazyBtn.isChecked = false
        main_populerBtn.isChecked = false
        selectCategery = SERIOUS

    }

    fun mainCrazyClicked(view: View?) {
        if (selectCategery == CRAZY) {
            main_crazyBtn.isChecked = true
            return
        }
        main_seriousBtn.isChecked = false
        main_funnyBtn.isChecked = false
        main_populerBtn.isChecked = false
        selectCategery = Funny

    }

    fun mainPopulerClicked(view: View?) {
        if (selectCategery == POPULAR) {
            main_populerBtn.isChecked = true
            return
        }
        main_seriousBtn.isChecked = false
        main_funnyBtn.isChecked = false
        main_crazyBtn.isChecked = false
        selectCategery = Funny

    }
}
```

> when i comment down the code below: application run fine..

```
commentClollectionRef.get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->
            for (document in snapshot.documents) {
                val data = document.data

                val name = data!![USERNAME] as String
                val timestamp = data[TIMESTAMP] as Date
                val comment = data[COMMENT] as String
                val numLikes = data[NUM_LIKES] as Long
                val numComments = data[NUM_COMMENTS] as Long
                val documentId = document.id

                val newThoughts = data_constructer(
                    name,
                    timestamp,
                    comment,
                    numLikes.toInt(),
                    numComments.toInt(),
                    documentId
                )

                comment_detail.add(newThoughts)
            }
            commentAdopter.notifyDataSetChanged()

        }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.e("Exception", "Could not add post:$exception")
        }
```

> how can i read the data from the firestore database give me the simple
> code example for kotlin if i want to upload and read the data ... as
> well as images on firebase..  help me out

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. Try reformating the quesiton so that we understand what your asking. Please don't dump code and expect us to magically solve it.

Comment: If your application crashes, there'll be an error message and stack trace in its logcat output. Please find those and add them to your question.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also respond with @.